# convert imageset.bin is missing

Tags: lmdb

I build `caffe` on windows.it ended succesfuly. Now in my `caffe/build/tools`   there is no convert `imagetset.bin`.

Where can I find or build(I already build caffe on windows with opencv installed and etc.) convert `imageset.bin`?

This is my code:

```
TOOLS=C:/projectcaffe/caffe/tools
DATA=D:/DATASET/aligned/
DEF_FILES=D:/DATASET/adel/Folds/train_val_txt_files_per_fold/test_fold_is_0
OUT=D:/DATASET/lmdb/Test_fold_is_0

# Set RESIZE=true to resize the images to 256x256. Leave as false if images      have
# already been resized using another tool.
RESIZE=true
if $RESIZE; then
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=256
  RESIZE_WIDTH=256
else
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=0
  RESIZE_WIDTH=0
fi




echo "Creating  train leveldb..."
GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset.bin--resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT    --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH --shuffle  $DATA $DEF_FILES/age_train.txt      $OUT/age_train_lmdb 

echo "Creating  train subset leveldb..."
GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset.bin--resize_height --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH --shuffle  $DATA $DEF_FILES/age_test.txt $OUT/age_test_lmdb 

echo "Creating  val leveldb..."
GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset.bin --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT  --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH --shuffle  $DATA $DEF_FILES/age_val.txt  $OUT/age_val_lmdb 



echo "Creating  train leveldb..."
GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset.bin --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH --shuffle  $DATA $DEF_FILES/gender_train.txt $OUT/gender_train_lmdb

echo "Creating  train subset leveldb..."
GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset.bin--resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH --shuffle  $DATA $DEF_FILES/gender_test.txt $OUT/gender_test_lmdb

echo "Creating  val leveldb..."
GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset.bin  --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH --shuffle  $DATA  $DEF_FILES/gender_val.txt $OUT/gender_val_lmdb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the following path if you compiled the caffe correctly.

```
/path_to_caffe-rc5/distribute/bin
```